# "demanded" vs. "needed"

Tags: word-usage

"demand" means

> to ask for something forcefully, in a way that shows that you do not expect to be refused

How about "demanded"? Consider this

> Computer training and Internet are highly **demanded**
>
> [source](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22are%20highly%20demanded%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)

Are "demanded" and "needed" interchangeable here?

> Computer training and Internet are highly **needed**

The results in [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are%20highly%20demanded%2C%20are%20highly%20needed%2C%20are%20highly%20REQUESTed&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20highly%20demanded%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20highly%20needed%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Care%20highly%20demanded%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20highly%20needed%3B%2Cc0) seem to be a YES. Although I am not sure about that. Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Demand" means that there is an active desire. For example, the sentence "there is a demand for computer training" suggests that many people want training, they are signing up for classes, the classes are filling up with students, etc.

"Need" does not have quite the same meaning as "demand." The sentence "computer training is highly needed" is somewhat ambiguous. It could mean that people want more computer training, but it could also mean that people lack computer skills, and it would be good to give them more training. Either meaning is possible, depending on context.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I got it. "Demand" does not imply that "people lack computer skills ...", right?

Comment: That's correct. Someone can demand something, even if they don't need it. Similarly, someone can need something that they don't want. I need exercise, but I don't want to exercise; I demand more desert, but I don't need it!

Comment: I got it. Thank you, that's very kind of you.

Comment: Oh dear. I misspelled "dessert". Even those of us who love the English language, screw it up occasionally.

Answer (score 2):

We say that something is *in demand* rather than *demanded*. "Trained computer technicians are in demand" means that there are plenty of job opportunities in that field. It's a slightly different usage of *demand* from the one meaning 'ask for something forcefully'.

We would say *greatly needed* rather than *highly.*

Comment: Thank you so much. When I use "in demand", it is also more idiomatic to say "greatly", right?

Comment: Yes - or _in great demand_.